# How to query two include dependency with OR in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a model Orcamento that have two dependency and I want to query then with a Op.OR. How do I do it? The models that I want to query are Pessoa and Contato.

```
static async findAllOrcamento(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
            let consulta: any = {
                pageCount: Number(req.query.pageCount) || 10,
                page: Number(req.query.page) || 0,
                searchValue:
                    req.query.searchValue == '""'
                        ? ""
                        : JSON.parse(req.query.searchValue as string),
                vendedor:
                    req.query.vendedor !== "undefined"
                        ? JSON.parse(req.query.vendedor as string)
                        : undefined,
            };

            let resultado: { orcamento: Orcamento[]; totalRecords: Number } = {
                orcamento: [],
                totalRecords: 0,
            };

            let queryWhere: any = {};

            if (
                consulta.searchValue !== "undefined" &&
                consulta.searchValue !== ""
            ) {
                if (!isNaN(Number(consulta.searchValue)))
                    queryWhere.id = consulta.searchValue;
                // else queryWhere["$Pessoa.nome$"] = { [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%" }
            }

            let wherePessoa = undefined;
            if (isNaN(Number(consulta.searchValue)))
                wherePessoa = {
                    nome: { [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%" },
                };

            if (req.query.deleted === "true")
                queryWhere = { ...queryWhere, deletedAt: { [Op.not]: null } };

            const include = [
                {
                    model: Vendedor,
                    include: [{ model: Pessoa, paranoid: false }],
                    where: consulta.vendedor
                        ? { id: consulta.vendedor.id }
                        : undefined,
                    paranoid: false,
                },
                {
                    model: Pessoa,
                    required:
                        isNaN(Number(consulta.searchValue)) &&
                        consulta.searchValue !== "undefined" &&
                        consulta.searchValue !== "",
                    where: wherePessoa,
                    paranoid: false,
                },
                { model: Contato, paranoid: false },
            ];

            resultado.orcamento = await Orcamento.findAll({
                limit: consulta.pageCount,
                offset: consulta.pageCount * consulta.page,
                where: queryWhere,
                paranoid: req.query.deleted === "true" ? false : true,
                include: include,
                order: [["id", "DESC"]],
            });

            resultado.totalRecords = await Orcamento.count({
                where: queryWhere,
                include: include,
                paranoid: req.query.deleted === "true" ? false : true,
            });

            return res.status(200).json(resultado);
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log("Request: ", req.body, "Erro: ", error);
            return res.status(500).json(error.message);
        }
    }
```

I tried to query on the principal where but I get a error that cant find de dependency.

I tried this:

```
    queryWhere[Op.or] = [
                {
                  "$Pessoa.nome$": {
                    [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%",
                  },
                },
                {
                  "$Contato.nome$": {
                    [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%",
                  },
                },
              ];
```

But a I get a error:

```
"missing FROM-clause entry for table \"Pessoa\""
```

Could some help me on this?

Comment: how does your `req` object looks like, could you share it by logging to console?

Comment: i was doing the resquest wrong on postman, the error that i got was "missing FROM-clause entry for table \"Pessoa\""

Answer (score 0):

I discover that in

```
queryWhere[Op.or] = [
  {
    "$Pessoa.nome$": {
      [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%",
    },
  }, {
    "$Contato.nome$": {
      [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%",
    },
  },
];
```

I was using the class name of the model 'Contato' and 'Pessoa' and i have to use the table name instead like that:

```
queryWhere[Op.or] = [
  {
    "$contato.nome$": {
      [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%",
    },
  }, {
    "$pessoa.nome$": { [Op.like]: "%" + consulta.searchValue + "%" },
  },
];
```